# Ruby: How do make my program trap and exit properly from a signal?

Tags: ruby, linux

When I Ctrl C my program on linux I often get output that looks similar to a stack-dump (a crash).

Can I catch the Ctrl-C signal and exit gracefully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trap signals with `Kernel.trap`:

```
trap('INT') do
  # exit gracefully
end
```